# How to make windows form in c# without rounded corners

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to make a windows form without rounded corners as below image. Are there any Windows API functions or any other methods to make it?

[image: No rounded corners]

I don't want to use `IMAGES` OR `FormBorderStyle = none` Properties.

WHEN REMOVE ROUNDED CORNERS,WINDOWS THEME COLOR SHOULD BE APPLY CORRECTLY.IT IS NOT BE WINDOWS CLASSIC MODE WINDOWS FORM

Comment: Why don't you want to use the border style property or images?

Comment: Rounded corners is my choice on my machine. Your app should work with the style I've chosen, not dictate a style.

Comment: Erm, a C#/WinForms app running on the same machine as that screenshot won't have rounded corners. Glad I could help.

Comment: I can create rectangular forms by disabling windows forms border with images.but I don't want it.I want to find a another way to do it.That's why I am looking for Win32 API code or windows graphics API cording.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to eliminate the rounded corders, you can set the [`Region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) property of the form:

```
this.Region = new Region(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
```

Comment: Your method is correct but windows styles are removed when it is applied

Comment: @Elshan That's the consequence of changing the window region. It cannot be avoided.

Comment: yes its OK,but then window themes are when changing MD.That's the reason.

Comment: any other methods? it cannot be change the windows default theme style for that  created window.(your method ok,it is removed rounded corners.but it will display as windows classic style window)

Answer (score 1):

Answer for 2022 / Windows 11.

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners

Sample Code - C# WinForms (more examples in link above):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WinFormsAppNet1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        // START: Change window border
        // The enum flag for DwmSetWindowAttribute's second parameter, which tells the function what attribute to set.
        // Copied from dwmapi.h
        public enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE
        {
            DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33
        }
        // The DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE enum for DwmSetWindowAttribute's third parameter, which tells the function
        // what value of the enum to set.
        // Copied from dwmapi.h
        public enum DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE
        {
            DWMWCP_DEFAULT = 0,
            DWMWCP_DONOTROUND = 1,
            DWMWCP_ROUND = 2,
            DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL = 3
        }
        // Import dwmapi.dll and define DwmSetWindowAttribute in C# corresponding to the native function.
        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
        internal static extern void DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd,
                                                         DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE attribute,
                                                         ref DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE pvAttribute,
                                                         uint cbAttribute);
        // END: Change window border

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // START: Change window border
            var attribute = DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE;
            var preference = DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE.DWMWCP_DONOTROUND; // DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE.DWMWCP_ROUND
            DwmSetWindowAttribute(this.Handle, attribute, ref preference, sizeof(uint));
            // END: Change window border
        }
    }
}
```